# How to create tabbed sections in JSF?

Tags: jsf, tabs

How To create tabbed sections in JSF? For example, in my home page, I need two tab sections namely, Personal and Official. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Which JSF implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Apache MyFaces with Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 2):

Richfaces offer a [`<rich:tabPanel>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/tabPanel.jsf) component. Note that the tab contents can be Ajaxified (i.e. retrieved using Ajax).

Answer (score 1):

If you use Trinidad, then this'll be of help - http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_panelTabbed.html